# Monad of monads to monads

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

Starting with scala monads. One can frequently run into situation of dealing with Monads of monad and requires it to convert into single monad for the ease of us. For example,

```
Set[IO[Either[A,B]] -> IO[Set[C]]
```

Though this can be achieved by converting into sequence and then map,

```
monadSet
.toList
.sequence[IO, Either[A,B]]
.map(...)
```

It gets complex when there is more than one,

Say `IO[IO[Set[Either[A,B]]]]` or `Future[Set[Either[A, Future[B]]`. How to handle these nested monads in general is not quite clear. Any resource on this would be helpful.

Edit: Nested monad of same type is not a problem usually. The main problem is nested monad of different types.

Comment: Haskell would deal with these using Monad transformers that allow you nest monads.  Someone can probably point to a better and more recent source, but you might try:  https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/scravy/realworldhaskell/materialien/monad-transformers-step-by-step.pdf

Comment: @MarcTalbot, that's the best I know of. There's just been one minor change to `Data.Map` that breaks one thing there: `lookup` now has a less general type. It's easy to work around this once you see that. The tutorial is also likely to be missing `Applicative` instances. And the `MonadFail` process is going to hit it soon enough. It'd be awfully nice to update the tutorial to keep up with the world.

Comment: Monad transformers have already been mentioned. [Here's](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/monad-transfomers.html) a tutorial on using them in the [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) scala library. And [this](https://github.com/atnos-org/eff) is a different approach to combining monads that also is a part of cats.

Comment: This seems like a misuse of the `haskell` tag as the question is about `scala`.

Comment: @hnefatl Thanks, yes it is. I wanted to know the general view on this, so added haskell. Removed it, nevertheless Scala answer would be sufficient.

Comment: In general monads don't compose, and when they do there's no general principle thst allows you to express this operation. Every pair of monads is different. This is the reason different transformers are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. Though in general monads don't compose, i find [herding cats monad transformers](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/monad-transfomers.html) solving the problem to an extent.

Especially `EitherT` and `optionT` wraps around the multiple monads and provides generic way of dealing with monads. They are just intuitive and this [blog](https://blog.buildo.io/monad-transformers-for-the-working-programmer-aa7e981190e7) also helps in understanding the motivation behind it.